# xamarin form ios doesn't display devexpress scheduler

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, devexpress, scheduler

I have a xamarin form project which implemented Devexpress scheduler on it and works well on android, but when I run ios on mac visual stodio, the page is blank and it doesn't even display the calendar. the nuget packege is installed on ios and androis and shared.

when i add this line to AppDelegate.cs :
DexExpress.xamarinForm.scheduler.iOS.initializer.Init();

it throw this error:
Could not create an native instance of the type 'DevExpress.Xamarin.iOS.Scheduler.DXDayView': the native class hasn't been loaded.
It is possible to ignore this condition by setting ObjCRuntime.Class.ThrowOnInitFailure to false.

and gives below errors when rebuild it:

.../project.iOS/MTOUCH: Error MT5211: Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class: DXAllDayAppItemViewProvider. The symbol '*OBJC_CLASS*$_DXAllDayAppItemViewProvider' could not be found in any of the libraries or frameworks linked with your application. (MT5211)

.../project.iOS/MTOUCH: Error MT5211: Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class: DXAllDayAppointment. The symbol '*OBJC_CLASS*$_DXAllDayAppointment' could not be found in any of the libraries or frameworks linked with your application. (MT5211)

I don't have any idea, please help me, it;s a while that I can't resolve thos issue!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a known issue about [Cannot create native types when deployment is executed to iPhone from VS for Windows without pairing to MAC](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/10800) on the github. And you can try [the workaound](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/10800#issuecomment-1305900017) in it.

In addition, someone has reported [MAUI - The 'Could not create an native instance' error](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t1121521/maui-the-could-not-create-an-native-instance-error) to the devexpress. And you can check the answer in it.

Finally, you cam also try to pair your Visual Studio to Mac or deploy your application from a Mac machine, because this problem seems to occur when a Maui application is deployed to iPhone from Visual Studio for Windows without pairing the VS to Mac .

Answer (score 0):

the problem was missing ios word in

appDlegate.cs file:
DevExpress.XamarinForms.Scheduler.**iOS**.Initializer.Init();

and also the last version of devExpress causing this issue, downgrade to older version fixed it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).